# How to pass input value inside filter function in Wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I have an issue with filter hook function,

So I have a form with input type number which I show in my template:

```
if( isset($_GET['submit']) ) {
    $my_text = esc_attr($_GET['my_text']);
}
?>
    <form id="my-form" method="get">
        <input id="my_text" type="text" name="my_text" value="<?php echo $my_text; ?>" />
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="search">
    </form>
<?php
```

So now I want when user type a text in this input and click submit button, the value should be passed inside my filter hook function:

```
function _themename_excerpt_more() {
    return 'here should be a value from input';
}

add_filter( 'excerpt_more', '_themename_excerpt_more' );
```

Is it possible? I can't find out right answers.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know particular answer for wordpress, but I can explain how this works in PHP in general. PHP is executed only once when the page is requested. After the response is sent to the client, you may not access any values in inputs or anything in html using that same PHP code. There are 2 ways to do that: either get the values in javascript

```html
<script>
document.getElementById('my-form').addEventListener('submit', () => {
  const input = document.getElementById('my_input')
  const value = input.value

  // Do something with this value
  alert(value)
})
</script>
```

The second option is to use html forms as "intended". When you press the submit button, user will be redirected to a page that you specify in `action` attribute. If it's empty, the user will be redirected to current page. And the value of your input will be in query parameters (`$_GET`) and have the name that you specify in `name` attribute. So you could use a different route (for example `/submit` or whatever would be appropriate for you application) and check the input there:

```html
<!-- Add name to input -->
<input 
  name="my_text"
  id="my_text" 
  type="text" 
  name="my_text" 
  value="<?php echo $my_text; ?>" 
/>
```

```php
function _themename_excerpt_more() {
    return $_GET['my_text'];
}

if(isset($_GET['my_text']) {
  // Don't forget to escape that if you need
  $value = $_GET['my_text'];
  add_filter('excerpt_more', '_themename_excerpt_more');
} else {
  // Replace with some more logic
  exit('Error: no input provided');
}
```

Or check it inside the function

```php
function _themename_excerpt_more() {
  if(isset($_GET['my_text']) {
    return $_GET['my_text'];
  } else {
    // Replace with some logic
    echo('Error: no input provided');
    // You may use a default value
    return 'default value';
  }
}

// Don't forget to escape that if you need
add_filter('excerpt_more', '_themename_excerpt_more');
```

Comment: thanks! I think the second one is better to use. What do you think about cookie? Is it a good to use it here?

Comment: @AkForDev well, it's not a bad practice or something, you can use them if you need. Don't forget to add `HttpOnly` flag if you store sensible information and remember that cookies can only hold 4Kb of data, though. Otherwise, it's fine